# SSRS Divide Sums from Different Scopes Returns 0

Tags: sql, reporting-services, expression, aggregate, division

I have a grouped dataset.  From the parent group down, the group names are:
Company >  Plant > Details.  In the end, I want to be able to take the sales of each plant and see what percentage it is of the entire company's sales.  Let's say the company has a total sales of $500 and the sales of "Plant A" were $100 and "Plant B" sales were $400.  I would image that I would need an expression at the Plant grouping level that was like:

```
=Sum(Sales)/Sum(Sales, "Company")
```

And I would get .2 for Plant A and .8 for Plant B.  But if I do that, I get 0.  I am at a complete loss.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Additional information:

My exact setup is a little more complex than the example I gave below, but I believe the general idea still holds the same.  I have a total of 6 groups:

[image]

The circled group is the equivalent of the "Plant" Group in my example.  Here is the row group in my tablix for the GroupBy group (the one with the arrow pointing to it).

[image]

The expression that is circled in the picture above is the expression in question to get my percentage (right now really just a decimal, not formatted to be a percentage yet).

```
 =sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value)/sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value, "Company")
```

Fields!ActualCurrent.Value is the equivalent of "Sales" in my example above.  The expression above returns 0 for all groups.  But yet, if I change it to

```
 =sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value)+sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value, "Company")
```

It will produce the equivalent of $600 for "Plant A" and $900 for "Plant B."

I can't seem to find how it reacts as expected when adding the two sums, but produces 0 when I divide them.

Comment: Did you try formatting the cell to show decimal digits? If you always get 0 it is possible the cell is formated to show integer numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be useful to see where are you using that expression to determine what is wrong here, but I think you can use this guide to get your desired result.

Create a tablix like this:

[image]

Note I've added `Company` and `Plant` fields as groups. Also I've deleted details group. Right click details and select `Delete group` and set Delete group only option.

[image]

Now in the percentage column use the following expression:

```
=FORMAT(
SUM(Fields!Sales.Value,"Plant")/SUM(Fields!Sales.Value,"Company")
,"P2"
)
```

The sum of every plan divided by the sum of the whole company group. It is not necessary but I am using `FORMAT` function to format the float value returned by the expression to percentage format using two decimal places.

It should show something like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:** Try scoping the sum to your specific group: `GroupBy`

```
=sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value, "GroupBy")/sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value, "Company")
```

**UPDATE 2:** Format the cell to show decimal digits.

Use thiss expression:

```
=FORMAT(
sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value, "GroupBy")/sum(Fields!ActualCurrent.Value, "Company"),
"F2"
)
```

It will format the value returned by the expression as a float with two decimal digits.

If you want to show the value in percentage format replace `F2` in the expression for `P2` (Percentage format with two decimal digits.)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I greatly appreciate you taking the time to respond.  I have added more info to my original post to show exactly what I am doing.  I believe that I am currently doing what you have in your response, yet I am getting different results.  Granted, I have been working on my report for far too long, so there is a great probability that I am missing something completely obvious.  Again I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @jenhil34, try my update. I think you are not aggregating sales in the correct context.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I tried it, and it still produces 0.

Comment: Try this expression in the cell `=1/4` if you get zero, just format the cell.

Comment: I am so sorry, yes, =1/4 is returning 0 as well.  Could you please expand on what you mean for format the cell?  I am going to blame my ignorance on my brain just being completely wiped out from this whole ordeal.

Comment: Oh wow.... on one hand, I am so unbelievably grateful for your help, on the other hand, just wow... how could I have missed this.  Thank you so much!!